# finding out how many values matched in a particular column for a particular row in a dataframe in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame:

```
X Y   Z 
1 ana python,ms-excel,C++,Aws
2 aba Python,MS-EXCEL,C++,AWS
3 ama Python
```

I need to know if columns Z has python, ms-excel or not.

So, maybe the outcome can look like:

```
X  Y    Z_new
1  ana  2
2  any  2
3  ama  1
```

The problem is I can parse, but there are too many columns, and it's hectic to find out which are similar to the columns names I need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's the possibility of repetitions in `'Z'` and you only want to count `'python'` once you would `nunique` instead of sum. `Series.str.extractall` is another way.

```
df['Z_new'] = (df['Z'].str.lower().str.extractall('(python|ms-excel)')
                      .groupby(level=0)
                      .nunique()  # .size() to count duplicates
              )
```

---

```
   X    Y                        Z  Z_new
0  1  ana  python,ms-excel,C++,Aws      2
1  2  aba  Python,MS-EXCEL,C++,AWS      2
2  3  ama                   Python      1
```

Comment: `df['Z'].str.lower().str.extractall('(python|ms-excel)').count(level=0)` also works to count all

Comment: @ansev good point! I was hoping `nunique` had a level argument, but sadly it didn't :p

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.lower`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) and [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with **`expand=True`**. Then use [`DataFrame.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) with [`DataFrame.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) to count:

```
df['Z-new']=(df['Z'].str.lower()
                    .str.split(',', expand=True)
                    .isin(['python', 'ms-excel'])
                    .sum(axis=1))
print(df)

   X    Y                        Z  Z-new
0  1  ana  python,ms-excel,C++,Aws      2
1  2  aba  Python,MS-EXCEL,C++,AWS      2
2  3  ama                   Python      1
```

**Detail**

```
print(df['Z'].str.lower().str.split(',',expand=True))
        0         1     2     3
0  python  ms-excel   c++   aws
1  python  ms-excel   c++   aws
2  python      None  None  None
```